# EF enumerate all ignored properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to get the names of all ignored properties of a given entity. The mapping is done via the fluent API, so I cannot simply check for the attribute.

I heard that I have to query the ObjectContext somehow, however, I cannot find any good internet resources on this topic.

```
var workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter) dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

var entityType = typeof(MyEntity);

IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ignoredProperties = workspace.??? // What here?
```

How to obtain a list of all ignored properties?

Additional note: I cannot alter the DbContext, so I cannot use the solution posted in [Get ignored properties in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760036/get-ignored-properties-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to create a static thread safe collection in your DbContext class and fill it when you ignore some property in mapping.

Add method to mapper class:

```
    public EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> IgnoreAndReport<TEntityType, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        this.Ignore(propertyExpression);

        LambdaExpression lambda = propertyExpression as LambdaExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpr = null;

        if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            memberExpr = ((UnaryExpression) lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        else if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;

        EntityMapData.IgnoredProperties.Add(new Tuple<Type, string>(typeof(TEntityType), memberExpr.Member.Name));

    }
```

Add class

```
public static class EntityMapData
{
    public static ConcurrentBag<Tuple<Type, string>> IgnoredProperties { get; set; } = new ConcurrentBag<Tuple<Type, string>>();
}
```

Replace the code in mapper (assuming you can change that):
`Ignore(m => m.SomeProperty)` to `IgnoreAndReport(m => m.SomeProperty);`

I didn't run the code but it should work.

Comment: As noted above, I cannot alter the DbContext and therefore cannot use the DbModelBuilder approach -> I also linked the very same post you did btw :-)

Comment: Sorry my bad... But you can create some other static class that holds your ignored property list, you don't need to modify the DbContext.

Comment: Sorry, so much effort on your part, but who's gonna call IgnoreAndReport()? Doesn't it mean I still have to fiddle with the original DbContext where the fluent mapping takes place? :(

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way via the ObjectContext as well?

Comment: You have your mappings in your DbContext class or you have separate files for entities and mappers? Here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-7-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration

Comment: No, mappings are all in the DbContext.partial.cs

Comment: Can you make your own subclass from the given DbContext? If so you should override the mappings in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: I could, but the other project would never instantiate it...so this is not going to work either.

Comment: Than my proposed solution will not work for you. Did you read this: https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/ I think after some debug you can find some information and you can compare your class with the mapped info and you can make a diff.

Comment: Good link, I'll give it a try!